(SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetObject operation
I'm trying to run an S3 copy operation via the aws cli. The object to be copied is large - its a single file at ~9GB.
aws cli s3 cp s3://${my_bucket}/${my_file}
I receive the following error:
download failed: s3://... to .. An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
When I try to run a list operation on the same bucket, there is no error.
I have verified that the IAM role has access to the S3 bucket, and it has both ls and cp permissions.

The error message does not match the actual underlying error.
The true issue is that the object being copied is too large. For my case, I can identify this pattern when the cp operation starts, and the progress bar appears, but is abruptly halted by the error.
This command solves the issue for me: aws configure set default.s3.multipart_threshold 10GB
The following issue mentions this:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4356
